# 422 Unprocessable Entity error when validation Ajax Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a problem from the beginning that I try to use Ajax request.

I got the 422 error when the validation is not valid. I hope you will be able to help me to resolved the problem.

Their is my controller :

I implement the use Validator

```
$validator = Validator::make($req->all(), [
            'nomRecette' => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['success' => false, 'errors' => $validator->errors()], 422);
        } else{
            return response()->json(['succes'=> 'sucessss']);
        }
```

My web :

```
Route::get('/mettre-a-jour/{type}/{id}', [RecetteCtrl::class, 'indexUpdateRecette'])->name('recette.viewUpdateRecette');

Route::post('/mettre-a-jour/recette', [RecetteCtrl::class, 'updateRecette'])->name('recette.updateRecette');
```

My view :

```
<form id='testForm'>
    @csrf
    <input type="text" name="nomRecette" id='nomRecette' value="">
    <input type="submit"></input>
</form>
    
    <script>
        $('#testForm').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            let nomRecette = $('#nomRecette').val();
            let crsf = $('input[name=_token]').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/recette/mettre-a-jour/recette",
                data : {nomRecette:nomRecette, _token:crsf},
                dataType: 'json',
          success: function (response) {
              console.log('le succes');
              console.log(response.success);
           },
           error: function(response, status) {
               console.log('mauvais');
             
           }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: have you tried this ```data: {'nomRecette' :  _token:crsf}```

Comment: Doesn't chanfe with nothing inside it

Comment: You've got 422 because validation. It's normal. So what's the problem?

Comment: @forcela you should be getting a `422` because you are not passing the validation. So, first of all, check your browser network tab and see the request, are you sending everything as expected ? Share an image with us. And try to avoid `Validator::make` there are better things like [`Form Requests`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation) or [`$request->validate()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic).

Comment: @Wahyu Kristianto I got the 422 error in the console so that’s a bit annoying for me and the user which will look into the console. I would like to catch this error to not display the error

Comment: @matiaslaurit I just passed the nomRecette and the token, and in the validator I just validate the nomRecette but in Model I put more thing into the fillabe array (like nomRecette, detail, etc etc) I’m not sure it causes the problem. For information it display the error in the console and I just want to catch it to just undisplay it

Answer (score -2):

Please try with this

{{ csrf_field() }}

Comment: The @csrf is the same than {{ csrf_field() }}. The difference is just the version of laravel